# How to add an if clause to a group of linux SHELL commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, command-line

I have a kubernetes deployment yaml file that runs a set of commands when a pod starts up.
How do I get the commands to execute only if a certain directory exists.

For example if I currently running these commands:
`mkdir $DIR; cd $DIR && git clone $URL;`

Is there a way to do this in a linux command line?
`if $DIR does not exist then {mkdir $DIR; cd $DIR && git clone $URL;}`

Comment: In leveraging the linked duplicate, note that checking for a directory specifically is `test -d` instead of `test -e`. And note that you need a space between the `{` and the `mkdir` in `{ mkdir`.

Comment: (one might consider `if ! test -d "$dir"; then (cd "$dir" && git clone "$url") || exit; fi` -- note using `( ... )` instead of `{ ...; }` is deliberate in that case: it creates a subshell, so the `cd` is scoped to the content inside the parenthesis and the directory the rest of your script runs in isn't changed; the use of lowercase variable names is also deliberate, as all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell and operating system, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use -- and in this context, your script is an application).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I think you have to reverse the logic in your codes snippet. You basically say _If $dir does not exist, then cd $dir_ .

Comment: Why don't you do a `mkdir -p "$DIR"` unconditionally? You then don't have to care about testing it existence.

Comment: @user1934428, I didn't reverse it -- rather, the mistake was leaving out the mkdir. Which isn't very relevant, because that part the OP already understands.